# Импорт данных в инфоблок битрикс из csv

Tags: битрикс, csv, импорт

Импортирую записи в инфоблок из csv файла.

Записи добавляются, все работает кроме одного момента.
В инфоблоке есть разделы для записей, пытаюсь добавить записи по разделам присвоив столбцам IC_GROUP0 и IC_GROUP1 название соответствующих разделов.

Но записи все равно падают в инфоблок, без присвоения раздела.

Как все таки загрузить записи по разделам инфоблока?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для раздела инфоблока поле "Символьный код" было помечено обязательным.
После снятия галочки, что поле обязательно, записи стали распределятся по разделам.